# Count Number Of Lines (Line Breaks) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas datafrme with a text column and was wondering how can I count the number of line breaks.This is how it's done in excel and would like to now how I can achieve this in python:

[How To Count Number Of Lines (Line Breaks) In A Cell In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4785-excel-count-newlines.html#:%7E:text=This%20formula%20%3DLEN(A2)%2D,0%20for%20a%20blank%20cell.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html)

```py
df['count'] = df['A'].str.count('\n')
```

```
print(df)

          A  count
0  a\nb          1
1   c\nd\nf      2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.count`:

```
df['Count lines'] = df['Data'].str.count('\n').add(1)
print(df)

# Output
                                   Data  Count lines
0                                 line1            1
1  new\nnew line1\nnew line2\nnew line3            4
2                  AA\nBB line\nCC line            3
```

Alternative with `str.split`:

```
df['Count lines'] = df['Data'].str.split('\n').str.len()
print(df)

# Output
                                   Data  Count lines
0                                 line1            1
1  new\nnew line1\nnew line2\nnew line3            4
2                  AA\nBB line\nCC line            3
```

You can remove `add(1)` if you want to count the number of line breaks and not the number of lines. In this case, for the `str.split` version, you have to append `.sub(1)` to get the number of line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, simply use [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

Number of line breaks:

```
df['breaks'] = df['your_col'].str.count('\n')
```

Number of lines (empty or not):

```
df['lines'] = df['your_col'].str.count('\n').add(1)
# or
df['lines'] = df['your_col'].str.count(r'(\n|$)')
```

To count only non-empty lines:

```
df['non-empty lines'] = df['your_col'].str.count(r'[^\n](\n|$)')
```

Example:

```
   your_col  breaks  lines  non-empty lines
0  abc\ndef       1      2                2
1       abc       0      1                1
2                 0      1                0
3        \n       1      2                0
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'your_col': ['abc\ndef', 'abc', '', '\n']})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a **lambda** function. Please see the following example.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "name": ["Uditha ", "this is \n Fun", "what\n on \nearth\n", "life", "ane palayan ban"],
    "age": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split("\n")))

print(df)
```

Comment: Note that using `apply` is inefficient in pandas, so is creating an intermediate `split` simply to count a character ;)